# Restore from .bak only imports system tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-restore

I was given a .bak from a MS SQL database and am needing to import the database onto a different workstation. I created a blank database in SQL Management Studio and attempted to restore from the .bak. The restore lists as successful, but only system tables appear in the restored database.

Am I missing a step?

Comment: Empty backup or wrong database you are looking at. Something like that. You are not missing a particular step.

Comment: @usr I'm restoring via GUI, would restoring via script yield different results? It's a 50mb file, which is about the size of the full database.

Comment: The script would reveal any misconfiguration that might not be apparent in the UI.

Comment: @usr Looking at the system tables, there are tables named 'backupfile' and 'restorefile' that mention other mdf and ldf files. Is it possible that I was given the wrong .bak type?

Comment: backupfile and restorefile are tables in the msdb system database. It sounds like you restored the wrong file. To check, do `restore headeronly from disk = 'name of file here'` and look at the DatabaseName column.

Comment: @BenThul Yup, that was it. This is why it was a successful load and had a decent file size, but no other tables. Post your comment as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the conversation in the comments, you had a backup of msdb rather than the database you wanted. You can do a `restore with headeronly from disk = 'name of file here'` to see what database is contained in the backup.